# Error: ORA-00925: missing INTO keyword] { errorNum: 925, offset: 6 }

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

i've query for insert if exist :

```
 MERGE TB_M_USER i USING ('TEST' as user_id, 'tes' as USER_NAME) d ON
 d.user_id = i.USER_ID WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT INTO (USER_ID,
 USER_NAME)  VALUES (d.user_id, d.USER_NAME)
```

but i got error:

> [Error: ORA-00925: missing INTO keyword] { errorNum: 925, offset: 6 }

even though I have added `INSERT INTO` to the query before

Comment: You want `MERGE INTO` and then `INSERT` without the `INTO`.

Answer (score 2):

It usually helps if you don't invent your own syntax, but follow the *official* one.

```
MERGE INTO tb_m_user i
     USING (SELECT 'TEST' AS user_id, 'tes' AS user_name FROM DUAL) d
        ON (d.user_id = i.user_id)
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN
   INSERT     (user_id, user_name)
       VALUES (d.user_id, d.user_name);
```